# Is there an api in workday to close purchase order

Tags: soap, xsd, workday-api

I am unable to find any API to close purchase order in workday. please help
there are API's to submit purchase order, cancel purchase order but not to close purchase in the API docs

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Import_Purchase_Order_Close_Lines](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Resource_Management/v37.1/Import_Purchase_Order_Close_Lines.html) with the description: "Closes purchase order lines for invoicing. You can't close lines associated to supplier invoices, receipts, or returns that are in draft or in progress. The entire purchase order is closed (displayed at the header) when the web service closes the last open line on the purchase order. "